# OS independent bare metal ARM interface for USB devices

Tags: usb, device-driver, assembly, arm

I was working through [**this tutorial**](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/input01.html) to create a basic OS for the Raspberry Pi. In this lesson, the author says that USB is insanely complicated and that he could not find some driver code to plug in that provides a simple USB interface for ARM processors. Is there such an open source library available?

#### Library purpose

Interface with USB devices on ARM architecture

#### Essential requirements

Provide functions available in ARM Assembly Language to interact with USB devices in a simple manner

#### License / budget

Free & Open Source